# Extending multiple recommended configurations in ESLint

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, static-code-analysis, eslint

**The Story:**

Currently, we are *extending the recommended ESLint configuration*:

```
{
  "extends": "eslint:recommended",
  ...
  "plugins": [
    "angular",
    "jasmine",
    "protractor"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "no-multiple-empty-lines": 2,
    "no-trailing-spaces": 2,
    "jasmine/valid-expect": 2
  }
}
```

And also using `angular`, `jasmine` and `protractor` ESLint plugins which also ship with *their own recommended configurations* (default rule strictness levels and default rule parameters).

**The Question:**

How can we use all the recommended configurations at the same time - the one that ESLint and all the used plugins ship with?

---

Tried the following:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:protractor/recommended",
    "plugin:jasmine/recommended",
    "plugin:angular/recommended"
  ],
  ...
}
```

but got the following error:

> Cannot read property 'recommended' of undefined

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> How can we use all the recommended configurations at the same time -
>   the one that ESLint and all the used plugins ship with?

Your syntax is correct, and multiple extensions are loaded like this:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:protractor/recommended",
    "plugin:jasmine/recommended",
    "plugin:angular/recommended"
  ]
}
```

However, this requires that the plugins in question actually come bundled with recommended settings. `eslint-plugin-angular` [does not](https://github.com/Gillespie59/eslint-plugin-angular#usage-with-shareable-config), and you have to install it yourself:

`npm install --save-dev eslint-config-angular`

Change your eslint settings to

```
{
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:protractor/recommended",
    "plugin:jasmine/recommended",
    "angular"
  ]
}
```

and it should work.

Comment: Shouldn't that be rather a comment than an answer?

Comment: @Daenu Yeah, probably. Updated my answer to better highlight the correct solution.

Comment: can we add `airbnb` as well to the `extends`?